# How to make the font size of the title larger than the largest

Tags: titles, fontsize

How can I increase the font of the title? For some reason it doesn't react to `\huge` or `\Large` etc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{caption}

\title{\Huge Latex}

\begin{document}
    
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

And also I can't center the title on the page. It turns out only indented  `\title{\Huge \\[5cm] Latex}`, but I think this is not correct and there should be an easier way.

Comment: you should not put formatting in `\title` but it does work, your example produces `\Huge` size text, centred on the page, so it is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the font changes. But the largest type is not enough to make a prominent title for a book.

Comment: You may want to re-write your question then as you currently explicitly say that `\large`, `\Huge` do not work. If your question is just how do you get a font bigger than Huge that is a duplicate (somewhere) you can use `\fontsize{2cm}{2.5cm}\selectfont` for example. But the size change should go into a `\maketitle` redefinition not into the `\title` argument.

Comment: yes, but even here it does not work well enough to enlarge the font

Comment: If you want to produce a book (and the titlepage for a book), you might want to use another document class than `article`, e.g., `book`.

Comment: @campa I get type1 fonts here (from cm-super in texlive)

Comment: Your question still says that the title does not react to `\huge` which means it is not possible to answer as it does select Huge font here, please edit.  I do not know how to respond to "does not work well enough to enlarge the font" what does "well enough" mean, it selects the font size that you specify exactly. If you get an error edit the question so it asks about the error and has an example that shows the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Uhm, then I'm doing something wrong... `:-(`

Comment: I just need a header in the full width of the page, I could not get it in any way